# How to save an image on AWS with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using node.js and would like to put on aws of the images I receive in base64. Everything goes well and loads them but when I open them it gives me an error, tells me that I am in the wrong form. And how do I get the image link to store it in the database?

The base64 form:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/......
```

The function that uploads the image:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({ params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET } });
                    let data = this.createData(req.body.image);
                    s3.putObject(data, (err, response) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(response)
                            /*tmp = task
                                .update(req.body)
                                .then(() => res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(task.id_creator)))
                                .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));*/
                        }
                    })

createData(image) {
    //TODO NOME CARTELLA
    let data = {
        Key: 'test1',
        Body: image,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    return data;
}
```

Everything goes well apparently, the response is:

```
{ ETag: '"20eaa681c71825d8f57472eb378be651"',
VersionId: 'kjQCDdfoq5H0Clhbs79SU4JiIUq8BgOn' }
```

But when I go in s3 console in my bucket if i download the image gives me an error ('format is wrong')

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a solution:
I just added

```
let buf = new Buffer(req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
```

And sent buf as data.
And I added an ACL parameter:

```
createData(image) {
    //TODO NOME CARTELLA
    let data = {
        Key: 'test1',
        Body: image,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    return data;
}
```